# How to get the Pod input data size in Kubernetes before running it?

Tags: input, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Is there a  Kubernetes API which can measure the input data size before running the PoD inside the Node ?

I need t use it as a it as parameter of a Kubernetes Scheduler function .

Comment: Hi, What do you mean Pod input data and its size?

Comment: I meant the amount of data that will be used by the Pod ( =the amount of memory will be allocated for the Pod )

Comment: I think you need to profile your pods to get the data of Memory and CPU, Its trial and error approach. That's why it's in the range (from request to limit) rather than any specific value.